# Configured Linux Machine to Authenticate to LDAP But not working

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, pam, pam-ldap

I am Using Cent Os Operating System and i need to configure LDAP Authentication for this machine. I have configured the ldap client using using authconfig-tui command. And i have cross checked the files ldap.conf and nsswitch.conf that whether they got updated or not. And they are fine.

I created one posixaccount user with all required attributes and now if i try to login it is giving me access is denied error.

I am logging into the machine through putty

Username:  testposix user
testposixuser's password: .......

Access is Denied

Please share any resources to configure LDAP Authentication to CentOS Machine

Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure ldap is enabled in PAM? Check /etc/pam.d/system-auth, etc. You mention ldap.conf and nsswitch.conf - ldap.conf configures how ldap is queried, and nsswitch.conf configures how identities are looked up, but you still need pam.conf for authentication. Also, there are two ldap.conf files - /etc/ldap.conf configures pam_ldap.so and libnss_ldap.so and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf configures defaults for the openldap library (although these aren't strictly needed if you put all the details in /etc/ldap.conf).

Further, you should check /var/log/secure for error messages. That would give you clues as to what is going wrong.

Finally, here are some basics on configuring LDAP Authentication on CentOS:
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-pam.html

Comment: Can you share any fine tutorial with you if you have any for configuring ldap with linux

Comment: @Sannisetty: Ask questions in questions, not comments.